# How to find people in a database who live in the same cities and already interacted with each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my Model:

```
Citizens (PK: citizenid ; name ; cityname ) 
Interactions (PK: id; role; process ; FK: citizenid )

declare @participants table (citizenid int, name nvarchar(100), cityname nvarchar(100))
declare @interactions table (id int identity(1,1), role nvarchar(100), process int, citizenid int)

insert @participants values (1, 'Jeff', 'miwaki')
    , (2, 'Geoff', 'jeffer')
    , (3, 'Jarrod', 'miwaki')
    , (4, 'Joel', 'jeffer')
    , (5, 'Karl', 'jeffer')

insert @interactions (role, process, citizenid) values ('defendant', 1, 1)
    , ('witness', 1, 2)
    , ('defendant', 1, 3)
    , ('defendant', 1, 4)
    , ('defendant', 1, 5)
    , ('witness', 2, 1)
    , ('witness', 2, 3)
    , ('accuser', 2, 2)
```

What I want is to get the `witness` and `defendants` of a court that participated in the same process and they are from the same city.

Desired Result:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║   Name        ║  Role        ║ Process  ║ City     ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  Geoff Dalgas ║ witness      ║  1       ║  jeffer  ║
║  Joel Spolsky ║ defendant    ║  1       ║  jeffer  ║
║  Karl Sapolsk ║ defendant    ║  1       ║  jeffer  ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    p.Name
    , i.Role
    , i.Process
    , p.CityName
FROM Participants p
    INNER JOIN Interactions i
        ON p.citizenID = i.citizenID
WHERE p.citizenID <> i.citizenID
      AND i.process = i.process
      AND p.cityname = p.cityName
      AND i.role <> 'accuser'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why does it not work? From the question it seems like you only need to join the two tables.

Comment: Try joining tables on PK and FK ,let us know if you are struck

Comment: The Join is OK, the thing I'm struggling is how to compare: witness.city = defendant.city considering the same process. Got it?

Comment: @Matt_Geo Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    p.Name
    , i.Role
    , i.Process
    , p.CityName
FROM Participants p
    INNER JOIN Interactions i
        ON p.citizenID = i.citizenID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Participants p2
                  INNER JOIN Interactions i2
                      ON p2.citizenID = i2.citizenID                
              WHERE p.citizenID <> i2.citizenID
                  AND i.process = i2.process
                  AND p.cityname = p2.cityName
                  AND i2.role <> 'accuser'
                  )
    AND i.role <> 'accuser'
```

Also, here's the full code for testing this out:

```
declare @participants table (citizenid int, name nvarchar(100), cityname nvarchar(100))
declare @interactions table (id int identity(1,1), role nvarchar(100), process int, citizenid int)

insert @participants values (1, 'Jeff', 'miwaki')
    , (2, 'Geoff', 'jeffer')
    , (3, 'Jarrod', 'miwaki')
    , (4, 'Joel', 'jeffer')
    , (5, 'Karl', 'jeffer')

insert @interactions (role, process, citizenid) values ('defendant', 1, 1)
    , ('witness', 1, 2)
    , ('defendant', 1, 3)
    , ('defendant', 1, 4)
    , ('defendant', 1, 5)
    , ('witness', 2, 1)
    , ('witness', 2, 3)

SELECT
    p.Name
    , i.Role
    , i.Process
    , p.CityName
FROM @Participants p
    INNER JOIN @Interactions i
        ON p.citizenID = i.citizenID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM @Participants p2
                  INNER JOIN @Interactions i2
                      ON p2.citizenID = i2.citizenID                
              WHERE p.citizenID <> i2.citizenID
                  AND i.process = i2.process
                  AND p.cityname = p2.cityName
                  AND i.role <> i2.role
                  AND i2.role <> 'accuser'
                  )
    AND i.role <> 'accuser'
```

Comment: I just realized one thing. I have more "Roles" in my interactions table, like "accuser". And if there's no witness in a process but there's a accuser with the same address as a defendant it's outputting this value to me and I don't want that. I want to make sure the comparison will be between defendant and witness for the same process. How do I get over this?

Comment: @Matt_Geo Just exclude the `accuser` altogether. Try now with my updated query.

Comment: Perfect! Now I understood how it works! Thanks for your patience and time! I really appreciated that! Wish you the best!